# Basic statistics with Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to characterize fractions of rows having certain properties using Apache Pig.

For example, if the data looks like:

```
    a,15
    a,16
    a,17
    b,3
    b,16
```

I would like to get:

```
    a,0.6
    b,0.4
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
    A = LOAD 'my file' USING PigStorage(',');
    total = FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) GENERATE COUNT(A);
```

which gives me total = (5), but then when I attempt to use this 'total':

```
    fractions = FOREACH (GROUP A by $0) GENERATE COUNT(A)/total;
```

I get an error.

Clearly COUNT() returns some kind of projection and both projections (in computing total and fractions) should be consistent. Is there a way to make this work? Or perhaps just to cast total to be a number and avoid this projection consistency requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the following modification of what @inquisitive-mind suggested works:

```
  total = FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) GENERATE COUNT(A);
  rows = FOREACH (GROUP A by $0) GENERATE group as colname, COUNT(A) as cnt;
  fractions = FOREACH rows GENERATE colname, cnt/(double)total.$0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to project and cast it to double:

```
total = FOREACH (GROUP A ALL) GENERATE COUNT(A);
rows = FOREACH (GROUP A by $0) GENERATE group,COUNT(A);
fractions = FOREACH rows GENERATE rows.$0,(double)rows.$1/(double)total.$0;
```

Comment: @inquisitive-mind Is there something wrong with the syntax? This code fails to parse in either pig-12 or pig-15. Complains about unexpected character line 4, column 40 (assuming that the LOAD operation is row 1). Thanks!

Comment: @TnatsissaHCraeser Try the dot. i.e. rows.$0,(double)rows.$1/(double)total.$0;

Comment: @nquisitive_mind This parses, but fails in a mysterious way (using the example above): "Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (3,1), 2nd :(15,1)". Note, that 1st comes from b,3 while the second from a,15 in the input. This seems to suggest that the mysterious scalar that has more than 1 row is actually 'total', and if so, it may be a projection problem...

Comment: What does DUMP total; give? more than 1 row?

Comment: @nquisitive_mind No, it doesn't. BTW, I mistakenly put $1 in my question, which made it into your answer (my apologies), but the error I'm seeing comes from the corrected version: "Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (a,3), 2nd :(b,2)"

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do the same:

```
test = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (one:chararray,two:int);
B = GROUP test by $0;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, COUNT(test.$0);
D = GROUP test ALL;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,COUNT(test.$0);
F = CROSS C,E;
G = FOREACH F GENERATE $0,$1,$3,(double)($1*100/$3);

Output:
(a,3,5,0.6)
(b,2,5,0.4)
```

Comment: this totally works, thanks!; not sure why the other solution, which looks simpler doesn't.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if this has helped :)

Comment: I posted an answer which constitutes an correction of another response I received. I believe it's better no to use CROSS in such situations as it's at least in principle computationally heavy.